# Does java remove/optimize unnecessary synchronized statements?

Tags: java, optimization, synchronized

Let's imagine someone synchronizes a method returning an int:

```
int whatever = 33;
...

public synchronized int getWathever() {
    return this.whatever;
}
```

We know from Java specs that ints are modified atomically. Hence, the `synchronized` statement is not necessary.

Will the compilers remove/optimize it?

Comment: Doubtful.  If you (the programmer) recognize it as unnecessary why specify it in the code?

Comment: I would not, but let's say I depend on 3rd party code or on code I did not write myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that simply is not possible. If the compiler and the JVM were to do so, it is likely that the constraints set by the *Java programming language memory model* would be violated.

More specifically, the *[synchronization order](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.4.4)* order stated in the Java Language Specification would be violated. If a compiler or a JVM<sup>*</sup> were to remove any "unwanted" synchronizations, then any further optimizations performed would violate any assumptions placed by a developer on the synchronization order (and the happens-before) relationship. In your specific case, any write to the integer will happen before the read, in a compiler/JVM that obeys the Java memory model.

A compiler/JVM that removes the synchronizations would simply result in an environment where the memory model is violated. For example, method in-lining could be performed without the compiler/JVM placing a memory barrier before the read of the integer value, thereby allowing for stale values to be read from a cached value.

<sup>*</sup> Note, the reference to the compiler/JVM duo is intentional. A compiler will only emit bytecode that complies with the JLS; a JVM could simply have a bug where the requirements of the memory model could still be violated. For the sake of completeness of the memory model, both the compiler and the JVM should comply with the requirements set by the memory model.

Comment: While this answer is basically identical to ratchet freak's one, I think it makes the behavior clearer - can I give +2?

Comment: Since HotSpot 1.6 it is possible. But it is not removed by the Java compiler, but by the JIT compiler. It is documented, that the performance penalty caused by unnecessary synchronization in `StringBuffer` or `Hashtable` versus `StringBuilder` or `HashMap` if they are used in single thread are minimal since HotSpot JVM 1.6. See http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp10185/

Answer (score 7):

synchronized has other thread safety effects besides getting a lock (ensuring the modified data is visible to other threads for one)

as long as these side effects are valid the JIT is essentially free to do what it wants

though in the example it has to ensure the lock is not held by any other thread during the loading of the variable which is easiest to ensure by effectively getting the lock

Comment: The first sentence is the important part here. Synchronized ensures a happens-before relationship to any subsequent invocation of **any** method of the object. So removing the synchronized changes the behavior here.

Answer (score 5):

There are cases when VM can eliminate a lock. For example

Escape analysis

```
int bar()
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    return foo.getWhatever();
```

VM can reason that foo is not visible to any other thread, therefore nobody else will try to lock it, therfore locking of the `getWhatever` method can be dropped.

Lock Coarsening

```
Foo foo = ...;
void bar()
    a();
    foo.getWhatever();
    b();
    foo.getWhatever();
    c();
```

can be legally merged to save one locking action

```
void bar()
    synchronized(foo)
        a();
        foo.getWhatever_without_lock();
        b();
        foo.getWhatever_without_lock();
        c();
```

Another good news is since the locked region is so short, due to adaptive locking, VM most likely will use spin lock for it; thread suspension due to failed locking is very unlikely.

Comment: Can you give a reference for this?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996783/what-is-the-synchronization-cost-of-calling-a-synchronized-method-from-a-synchro

Answer (score 4):

It's absolutely not safe to remove that "synchronized" if the intent is to make it thread-safe unless you ensure the int variable is properly synchronized to main memory in some other way, so in this case, no.

Comment: But (unless I am wrong) only modifications to long and double require volatile, no?

Comment: No, unless you'll only ever run this program on a single-core processor. It's not about atomic writes and reads. It's about values being transferred back and forth between CPU caches and main memory. On a multi-core machine with multiple threads operating and no "synchronized", different threads could and almost certainly would see different values for the same variable because each core will have a different value in its cache from the others and from main memory.