# HotSpot JVM optimizations for nested synchronized blocks

Tags: java, optimization, synchronization, synchronized, jvm-hotspot

Does the HotSpot JVM (in Oracle JDK 7 & 8) optimize for nested `synchronized` blocks that synchronize on the same object?

e.g., is the first code listing (class `A`) just as efficient as the second code listing (class `B`)?  (class `B` avoids the nested `synchronized (x)` that occurs in class `A`)

```
public class A {
    private final Object x = new Object();

    public void a() {
        synchronized (x) {
            // code snippet 1
            b();
            // code snippet 2
        }
    }

    public void b() {
        synchronized (x) {
            // code snippet 3
        }
    }
}

public class B {
    private final Object x = new Object();

    public void a() {
        synchronized (x) {
            // code snippet 1
            c();
            // code snippet 2
        }
    }

    public void b() {
        synchronized (x) {
            c();
        }
    }

    private void c() {
        // code snippet 3
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the synchronization cost of calling a synchronized method from a synchronized method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996783/what-is-the-synchronization-cost-of-calling-a-synchronized-method-from-a-synchro)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is even a VM option for that appeared in JDK 7 (on by default):

```
-XX:+EliminateNestedLocks
```

However, it seems to work only when monitor object is `static final` or when locking on `this` object.

Answer (score 0):

In cases when `b` is short enough to be inlined, I hope so. Otherwise no, as the inter-procedural analysis is too complicated and the gain limited (what can't be inlined takes probably so long that some overhead is acceptable). But then you can still profit from biased locking.

This is just a guess, but even JDK6 does [lock coarsening](http://www.infoq.com/articles/java-threading-optimizations-p1), which can be thought of as a more complicated version of what you're asking about. After inlining we have

```
public void a() {
    synchronized (x) {
        // code snippet 1
        synchronized (x) {
            // code snippet 3
        }
        // code snippet 2
    }
}
```

while lock coarsening starts with something like

```
public void a() {
    synchronized (x) {
        // code snippet 1
    }
    synchronized (x) {
        // code snippet 3
    }
    synchronized (x) {
        // code snippet 2
    }
}
```

This is a more complicated case as here joining the synchronized blocks can reduce throughput, while in your case there's absolutely nothing to lose.

Comment: You have lock coarsening to front. The transformation you've shown here isn't valid. Or else you haven't made yourself clear.

Comment: @EJP "coarsening to front." ? You lost me. My second example is lock coarsening. The first one is just a removal of the acquisition and release of an already held lock.