# Java synchronized method calling not synchronized method

Tags: java, synchronization

I have code like this:

```
public class Example {
    public synchronized void doSomething() {
        // ...
        doSomethingElse();
        // ...
    }

    private void doSomethingElse() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Since `doSomething` is the only place where `doSomethingElse` is called and `doSomething` is synchronized, is it still necessary to make `doSomethingElse` synchronized?

The Java Language Specification says in the [beginning of chapter 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html) on Classes: "A synchronized method [...] automatically locks an object before executing its body and automatically unlocks the object on return". I'd assume that calling another method is not returning, so the above code should be correct.

[JLS example 8.4.3.6-1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6) on synchronized monitors seems to confirm my understanding.

On the other hand, I guess making `doSomethingElse` synchronized won't hurt; except maybe for a small performance hit as per  [What is the synchronization cost of calling a synchronized method from a synchronized method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996783/what-is-the-synchronization-cost-of-calling-a-synchronized-method-from-a-synchro) (which I don't care that much about; correctness is more important).

Am I missing something?

Comment: Apart from the fact that it isn't very good practice to synchronize on objects visible from the outside, the code is fine.

Comment: @biziclop could you please elaborate on why is is bad practice to synchronize visible (i.e. public) functions?  Any references?

Comment: @user949300 Not visible functions, synchronizing on visible objects that is the problem. (In your case, you synchronize on `this`.) And the problem is that if you create an object and pass it to some unknown code (`Example ex = new Example(); foo.doSomethingWith( ex )`), that code can also synchronize on `ex`, thus interfering with your synchronization.

Comment: @biziclop Interesting, I'll think about it.  However, you are effectively saying "never use synchronized in a method declaration".  I've heard of many (too many) design patterns, "effective" things, and coding principles, but never that one.  :-)

Comment: @user949300 Yes, essentially that's what I'm saying. Or rather "avoid if possible", because sometimes you have no other option. The idea isn't mine though, you can read more about it in item 70 of Effective Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is it still necessary to make `doSomethingElse` synchronized?

No. Since the method is private, and the only context in which it could be called is synchronized as well, `doSomethingElse` does not need to be synchronized.

Note that it does not hurt to make `doSomethingElse` synchronized, for two reasons:

- In case someone else changes your code to call `doSomethingElse` from some other place that is *not* synchronized, you would be safe. Re-entering a lock that the thread already owns is very cheap, so you do not need to worry about performance consequences.
- When other people read your code, and see you accessing shared resources from `doSomethingElse` without synchronization, they are not surprised at how you can get away with that.

Also note that it is important that both methods are non-static. Had `doSomethingElse` been `static` and needed access to *mutable* static resources, you would need to synchronize it separately from `doSomething`.

Comment: Correct, but...  Note that making `doSomethingElse()` **synchronized** might be a good idea in case in the future it ever gets used somewhere else.  (or at least put in a comment warning future coders).  Also, the JVM is supposedly very efficient at obtaining synchronized locks where the thread already has a lock - i.e. calling many nested synchronized methods is (theoretically) very fast.

Comment: @user949300 Thanks for the comment, I edited the answer to reflect that point.